# SpinCtrl with step increment value

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a custom SpinCtrl with a step increment. It seems like such a simple thing so I was surprised the native SpinCtrl doesn't appear to have this functionality, and Google proves uncommonly useless in this matter as well.

When I try to make a custom one, however, I run into problems. Here's some quick and dirty code

```
class SpinStepCtrl( wx.SpinCtrl ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( SpinStepCtrl, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )

        self.step = 99

        self.Bind( wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpin )
        #self.Bind( wx.EVT_SPIN_UP, self.OnUp )
        #self.Bind( wx.EVT_SPIN_DOWN, self.OnDown )

    def OnSpin( self, event ):
        print 'X'
        self.SetValue( self.GetValue() + self.step )
```

The *print* is just there so I can see what, if anything, happens. The EVT_SPIN_UP and EVT_SPIN_DOWN events don't seem to work at all, at least the callbacks are never called which is why I took them out.

When using EVT_SPINCTRL, the callback is called, but end up in an infinite loop because *SetValue* apparently causes a new such event to be called. It doesn't help much either way, because I can't find a way of telling whether it was a spin up or spin down event, so I can't change the value appropriately.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Could you UNbind the wx.EVT_SPIN_UP/_DOWN/ and wx.EVT_SPINCTRL from the parent SpinCtrl? This way you avoid the recursion. And then you may be able to use the _UP/_DOWN events in your control.

Comment: I have tried unbinding first thing in the OnSpin() method, then rebinding after the call to SetValue, if that is what you mean. It doesn't seem to work, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, not the best, but works on Ubuntu:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx

class SpinStepCtrl(wx.SpinCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.SpinCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.step = 99
        self.last_value = 0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.OnSpin)

    def OnSpin(self, event):
        delta = self.GetValue() - self.last_value
        if delta == 0:
            return
        elif delta > 0:
            self.last_value = self.GetValue() + self.step
        else:
            self.last_value = self.GetValue() - self.step
        self.SetValue(self.last_value)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.spin = SpinStepCtrl(self.panel, min=0, max=1000)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Still, I would consider "self.SetValue" generating "wx.EVT_SPINCTRL" a bug.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not too confident about reporting bugs, though. But at least this workaround solves the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: spinctrl.SetValue should not generate an event, most 'newer' controls work that way, i.e. a programmatic setting should not fire a setting event.  See e.g. http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/SpinCtrl.html?highlight=spinctrl#SpinCtrl.SetValue

Answer (score 3):

wx.lib.agw has [floatspin](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.floatspin.html) widget which has more options. I use it with SetDigits(0) for integer input as well.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.floatspin as FS

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "FloatSpin Demo")

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        floatspin = FS.FloatSpin(panel, -1, pos=(50, 50), min_val=0, max_val=1000,
                                 increment=99, value=0, agwStyle=FS.FS_LEFT)
        floatspin.SetDigits(0)


# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the standard `wx.SpinCtrlDouble` can be used in the exact same way as this. Note: you will need to cast the result of `GetValue()` to an `int` if that is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import wx

class SpinStepCtrl(wx.SpinCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.SpinCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.step = 99
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPIN_UP, self.OnUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPIN_DOWN, self.OnDown)

    def OnUp(self, event):
        self.SetValue(self.GetValue() + self.step)

    def OnDown(self, event):
        self.SetValue(self.GetValue() - self.step)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.spin = SpinStepCtrl(self.panel, min=0, max=1000)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work for me. The program runs, but the SpinCtrl counts up by 1 as usual. I've had a similar problem recently where something worked for others but not for me, could it be a bug? I'm running on Ubuntu 10.10, python 2.6.6 and wxPython 2.8.11

Comment: Hmmm. I am running this setup: Windows XP-SP3, Python 2.7, wxPython 2.8.11.0.

Comment: I tried on Windows 7, same python and wxPython (2.6.6 and 2.8.11.0), and there it works just fine too.

Comment: I have recently seen the comment, that wx.EVT_SPIN_UP, wx.EVT_SPIN_DOWN, and wx.EVT_SPIN are events of wx.SpinButton, only event for wx.SpinCtrl is wx.EVT_SPINCTRL. Weird that using wx.EVT_SPINCTRL does not freeze on Windows either.

Comment: Hmm. If I could just get EVT_SPINCTRL to work then, that'd be ok. What I need is a way to test what exactly the event was, whether the up or down arrow was pushed, or if the event was caused by something else.

Comment: @MCXXIII you can use the Widget Inspection Tool to see what events are firing. just add `import wx.lib.inspecton as inspect` `inspect.InspectionTool().Show()` before you enter the **app.MainLoop()**.

Comment: @Fenikso the other events (wx.EVT_SPIN_UP, etc) of the SpinButton are available on the SpinCtrl as well; wx.EVT_SPINCTRL is an additional one that is available for the SpinCtrl. The catch is that EVT_SPINCTRL is available on all platforms, but the events of the SpinButton may not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for **wxSpinCtrl, which takes values from a list to spin.**
It is a pity that the events EVT_SPIN_UP and EVT_SPIN_DOWN from wx.SpinButton do not work under all platforms (not working here with wx 4.0.6 and Windows 10 / 64 Bit)

```
import wx

class SpinCtrlList(wx.SpinCtrl):
    """A SpinCtrl that spins through a given list. This list must be in
    ascending order and the values of the list must be integers,
    whereat negative numbers are allowed
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.SpinCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self._on_spin)
        self.thelist = ([0,1])
        self.SetList([0, 1])
        self.SetValue(self.thelist[0])

    def SetList(self, thelist):
        self.thelist = thelist
        self.SetRange(self.thelist[0], self.thelist[len(self.thelist)-1])

    def GetList(self):
        return self.thelist

    def SetValue(self, val):
        self.sp_old_value = val
        super(SpinCtrlList, self).SetValue(val)

    def _next_greater_ele(self, in_list, in_val):
        for x, val in enumerate(in_list):
            if val > in_val:
                break
        return val

    def _next_smaller_ele(self, in_list, in_val):
        for x, val in enumerate(reversed(in_list)):
            if val < in_val:
                break
        return val

    def _on_spin(self, event):
        self.sp_new_value = self.GetValue()
        #print(self.sp_old_value, self.sp_new_value)
        if self.sp_new_value > self.sp_old_value:
            set_val = self._next_greater_ele(self.thelist, self.sp_new_value)
            self.SetValue(set_val)
            self.sp_old_value = set_val
        elif self.sp_new_value < self.sp_old_value:
            set_val = self._next_smaller_ele(self.thelist, self.sp_new_value)
            self.SetValue(set_val)
            self.sp_old_value = set_val


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.spin = SpinCtrlList(self.panel)
        ctrl_list =[100,  200,  500,  1000, 2000,  5000, 10000, 12000, 15000]
        #ctrl_list = [-300, -100, 0]
        self.spin.SetList(ctrl_list)
        self.spin.SetValue(ctrl_list[-2])
        self.Show()

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```